# CSS Column Count - Change order

Tags: html, css

I want to change the order of the columns here:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}

#column-wrapper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px; 
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 20px;
}

#column-wrapper .column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="column-wrapper">
        
        <div class="column">
            <span>1</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <span>2</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <span>3</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <span>4</span>
        </div>
        
         <div class="column">
            <span>5</span>
        </div>
        
         <div class="column">
            <span>6</span>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

The result should be this:
[image: Column Count]

Does anyone know a simple solution for this?

Comment: You cannot change the html markup? :O

Comment: OP, I edited your question to use a code snippet because the relevant code should be in the question. Please do it yourself next time.

Comment: Is it necessary to use column-count? Why not float them ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you using columns when you want a row based order ? Looks like a job for [the flex model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Without changing your HTML you can do this:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}

#column-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap
}

#column-wrapper .column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(30% - 20px);
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="column-wrapper">
        
        <div class="column">
            <span>1</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <span>2</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <span>3</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <span>4</span>
        </div>
        
         <div class="column">
            <span>5</span>
        </div>
        
         <div class="column">
            <span>6</span>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work when flex-items ("column") align in this way, even when they have different heights?! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `column` show in CSS. Use `float` instead, it's natural document flow.

```
.column {float: left; width: 140px;}
.column:nth-child(3n+2) {margin: 0 20px;}
.column:nth-child(3) ~ .column {margin-top: 20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/70nk1a1n/1/

Comment: In this example yes. But in my project the width of the #container is flexible.

Comment: @ironman: so you can use `%` in width and margins/paddings :-) Everything is possible, but when you need to show bloks from left to right (natural document flow), it's non-sense to use column grid to do it.

Comment: Ok, that's true :) But if I have 100 rows, there are problems with the margin or?

Comment: @ironman: really don't know, what you have there :-). It works with many rows, I've just changed `px` to `%`. - http://jsfiddle.net/70nk1a1n/2/

Comment: Oops I am sorry. So this is a good solution. And what solution is better :D

Comment: @ironman: solution with flex/columns grid is relatively easy to understand but has smaller browsers support. This solution will work in almost all browsers. Using percents it's responsive, so it's up to you. I use this one, due to the browsers support.

Comment: I'll take this one. Thanks again for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

this is funny, rotate page and content. the edit below describes a pitfall to this for columnCount.  the real solution follows

```
<div ref={this.columns} style={{
 columnCount:Math.round(window.innerWidth*1 / 300)/1,
 transform: "rotate(180deg)"//rotate page, same as scale(-1,-1)
}}>
<div style={{
 transform: "scale(-1,-1)",//flip && reverse column content (parent)
 width:"100%,//so children are not lost when scrolled offscreen y
 breakInside:"none"// "" not pushed to next column when ""
}}></div>
</div>
```

edit: this seems to break the `columnCount` unspoken rule of maintaining [`width:100%` and `columnGap:"1px"` or something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433552/css-column-count-change-order/66124177#66124177) on column content, losing the `backgroundColor` in my case, for some other SO `columnCount` questions media is lost when scrolled offscreen. I don't believe I can make the component render the rotation first, then apply `columnCount` to maintain it, so I am 90% sure the only solution is to reverse your `sort` and use `parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollHeight - columns.offsetHeight` and `parent.scrollLeft = parent.scrollWidth - columns.offsetWidth`